# Jackson Json parser does not parse strictly. Solution?

Tags: java, json, jackson

The following string is an invalid JSON string according to http://www.json.org/

```
"billPeriod":{"from":"2011-6-1","to":"2011-6-28"}}
```

It is missing a closing brace at the start.

However, when I pass this through the Jackson Json parser, it returns a JsonMappingException rather than a JsonParseException.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String input = "\"billPeriod\":{\"from\":\"2011-6-1\",\"to\":\"2011-6-28\"}}"
mapper.readValue(input, clazz.class);
```

Can anyone help? I've looked but can't find a variable setting to increase the "strictness" of the parsing.

Thanks
Dan

Comment: If you think it's a bug, then file it on the Jackson JIRA. The maintainer is pretty responsive.

Comment: Was mainly wondering if anyone else has encountered this before and whether it is a "feature" that the parser can interpret and fix the missing brace. And thanks, will also post with Jackson

Comment: On second thoughts, it may be an efficiency issue. It's much faster to fail if the ObjectMapper tries to build the object from the json first rather than validating the syntax then trying to build the object. hmmm....

Comment: If at all there is a feature to do this in Jackson, it should be part of the serialization config feature. Did you look in to the api document for this.?